# One model binder to rule them all or a bunch of them?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need some assistance in my understanding!

I want to understand how best to have Model binding being used by my asp controllers. Basically I want to have a reference in my session to something to a master object (cart) and my user will be editing a model (editingModel1)in a form they have requested.

Basically I was thinking of having a class like this:

```
   public class customModelBinder : IModelBinder {
        private const string sessionKey = "Cart";

        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
            ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {

            // get the Cart from the session 
            Cart cart = (Cart)controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey];
            // create the Cart if there wasn't one in the session data
            if (cart == null) {
                cart = new Cart();
                controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey] = cart;
            }
            // return the cart
            return cart;
        }
    }
```

and using it in my controller like this

```
      public ActionResult Edit(int id, Cart cb)
        {
            Company c = _companyProvider.Read(id);
            cb.editingModel1 = c
            return View(c);
        }
```

If I want a user to interact with another thing like editingModel2 should I also put it in the cart

Hope this explains my issue!

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would abandon the custom model binder. ASP.NET's default model binder combined with the power of strongly-typed `Html.____For` controls is extremely powerful and should be taken advantage of.

I am assuming that a `Cart` is essentially a list wrapped in a class containing some metadata. What I would do is create a strongly-typed view containing a form and `for` controls to edit an object containing the data that you are interested in. Let's call this object type `MyItem`. Then, have the form submit to a controller which will take a parameter of type `MyItem`. This parameter will be filled with the data from the form. What you can then do is use the `Session` variable to access the `cart` object, and the object of type `MyItem` to it.

Overall this requires very little logic, as most of it is baked right into the MVC framework. Handle this in a controller, possibly using a helper class depending on your architecture, and leave the worries about model binding to MVC.

---

Don't use hidden fields! You don't need them. I think what you may not understand is that when you have the `Session` variable in MVC, you are essentially working with it as if it was a single session of a single user. If you use the code `Session["MyCart"]` to access the cart in session, a user which runs that code will get access to his or her cart automatically. This is because session unicity is managed by MVC automatically in a secure fashion. You as the developer don't need to worry about a user accessing the server-side items which correspond to them. Just put them in session and MVC takes care of the rest, ensuring that a user only has access to the session data that belongs to them.

Comment: Hi! what I liked about the model binder using the Cart was that I could immediately access it in the controller and not have to pass extra variables like ID to client to be stuff in Html.For as they could be tampered with...

Comment: your approach was what I first was doing, using hidden fields

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood how MVC manages the session. See updated answer.